# Check if an object type exists in the array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an abstract class that call Car.

```
    abstract class Vehicles {
}
```

I have more 3 classes ,which inheritance Car :

```
class Car extends Vehicles {
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicles {
}

class Truck extends Vehicles {
}
```

I want to make a random array that his type is Vehicles:

```
let vehicles1: Vehicles [] = new Array(2);
```

But i don't want repeat the same Vehicles type twice.(There will be no two cars for example)
I can check every type the object that was created ,but if i have 20 classes that extends Vehicles ?

How i can to check if the object, was already created in array or not? but witout alot of if check? (typeof)

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use findIndex to insure there is no other items of the same type, here is an example of the function that adds a new item to the vehicles1 array but before that it tests for any existing items of the same type:

```
function addVehicle(vehicle) {
        const thisType = typeof vehicle;

        const index = vehicles1.findIndex(el => typeof el === thisType);
        if(index !== -1) {
            // that means there is no item of the same type, So you can add this one
        }
}
```

Comment: I use your function , but the type of vehicle is always object (and not car/Motorcycle/Truck) so the if  condition always be true and its not work and makeing a random array